# How to create a folder in internal storage in Android 4.4 when SD card (External storage) is present

Tags: android

I am working on an application where i need to create folder in the internal storage (phone memory) when the SD card is also available. I am using the `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+folderName;` when i run this widout SD card it create folder in Internal but after inserting SD card when i run the same it create folder on SD card. But i want to create folder in Internal Storage.

Here is my Code

```
    private static File contactsFile;
    private static String contacts_storage_path;

    contacts_storage_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/"+folderName;
            contactsFile = new File(contacts_storage_path);
            if (!contactsFile.exists())
            {
                 //contactsFile.createNewFile();
                contactsFile.mkdirs();
            } 
             filecontact=new File(contactsFile, contact_file_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to use [Context.getDir(String value, int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) to create directory in internal storage.

Refer below code -

```
File mydir = context.getDir("mydir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); //Creating an internal dir;
File fileWithinMyDir = new File(mydir, "myfile"); //Getting a file within the dir.
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileWithinMyDir); //Use the stream as usual to write into the file.
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder in Internal memory like this:

```
File dir = context.getDir("dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
dir.mkdirs();
```

Comment: But i don't want to make this folder private to my application which might get deleted when i uninstall my app. I simply looking for a folder in Internal Storage and that should be there if i uninstall my application also.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
**File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();**
**File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolderName");**
dir.mkdirs();
//to know the path
Log.d(TAG, dir.getAbsolutePath();
String fileName = String.format("%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis());
File outFile = new File(dir, fileName);
outStream = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Hope this helps!